# Java Regex in round brackets

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to parse an input string like this

```
String input = "((1,2,3),(3,4,5),(2,3,4),...)"
```

with the aim of getting an array of String where each element is an inner set of integers i.e.

```
array[0] = (1,2,3)
array[1] = (3,4,5)
```

etc.

To this end I am first of all getting the inner sequence with this regex:

```
String inner = input.replaceAll("\\((.*)\\)","$1");
```

and it works. Now I'd like to get the sets and I am trying this

```
String sets = inner.replaceAll("((\\((.*)\\),?)+","$1")
```

But I can't get the result I expected. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `replaceAll` to remove the parentheses at the ends. Rather use `String#substring()`. And then to get the individual elements, again rather than using `replaceAll`, you should use `String#split()`.

```
String input = "((1,2,3),(3,4,5),(2,3,4))";
input = input.substring(1, input.length() - 1);

// split on commas followed by "(" and preceded by ")"
String[] array = input.split("(?<=\\)),(?=\\()");

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

Comment: @lowcoupling Those are look-behind and look-ahead respectively.